# How to read in data with space separated strings and digits?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt file formatted as shown below. Is there a handy way to read in the data and only use "real" \s+ as separators? Meaning that single spaces are not read as separators, but multiple spaces are.
By now pandas is creating a separate column for every string, resulting in 4 columns instead of 3.

Thanks for any help or idea!

```
Hello World       3    2
Banana Pancakes   4    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the regex “\s\s+” as a separator.

This separator works on cases of multiple, but not single, spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
s = 'Hello World       3    2'
import re
list_ = re.split(r'\s{2,}', s)
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
['Hello World', '3', '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Hari's answer above, you can use re.split() with his suggested regex pattern:

```
>import re
>line = "Hello World       3    2"
>pat = re.compile(r'\s\s+')
>pat.split(line)
['Hello World', '3', '2']
```